# jQuery and mobile browser compatibility?

Tags: jquery, iphone, android, mobile, jquery-mobile

I want to build a relatively simple version of my site for mobile phones, but I will definitely need JavaScript and jQuery for many functions.

Googling didn't help to find an answer. How is compatibility of jQuery with popular browsers in mobile phones?

I am talking for smartphones. For example, the default browsers for these platforms

- [Windows Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile) 6+
- Android 1.5+
- [iPhone 3G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_3G)

and let's add [Opera Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mobile).

Comment: http://www.jqtouch.com/ might be interesting for you as well: "A jQuery plugin for mobile web development on the iPhone, iPod Touch, and other forward-thinking devices"

Comment: it's out; official jQuery for mobile: http://jquerymobile.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

jQuery should work fine on at least the Android and iPhone web browsers (don't know about WinMo), as they fully support JavaScript and are for the most part standards compliant.

If you expand a little bit on which specific features of jQuery you're using, I or others can give a better answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will probably need dom manipulation and ajax with the jquery load function

Comment: My Nexus One with Android 2.2 performs better on http://jquery.com/test/ than my desktop Chromium (5.0.375.99 (51029) Ubuntu 10.04). They fail on almost the same points thought...

Comment: try it on Pocket Internet Explorer, then say it's compatible.

Comment: Even on the same android phone, using different browser "skins" i get different results. my jquerymobile page works just fine on the default browser. now using the dolphin browser (i need my tabs) the list items aren't clickable.  Code of the page is copy/paste from the docs.

Answer (score 4):

The [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) framework uses jQuery and has support for [many mobile platforms](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/). All browsers that jQuery Mobile works on should be passing the jQuery test suite.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [factsheet](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/08/jquery-mobile.html), there will be jQuery Mobile in October 2010. So we don't need to think about mobile compatibility ever again :))

Answer (score 2):

See *[What's jQuery's mobile support & strategy?](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/6d0f9da66581d9ca/819ff599f546ec65?lnk=gst&q=jquery+mobile#819ff599f546ec65)*. iPhone, Android, and similar [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) browsers should be compatible. I think you will have [many problems with Windows Mobile](http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/jquery-on-internet-explorer-mobile/).

Answer (score 1):

Both Android and iPhone are full featured WebKit browsers (bar plugins). I would be highly surprised if it doesn't work on those.

Comment: question is more about data than guessing

Answer (score 1):

They now have [a browser compatibility matrix](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) like YUI.

Comment: Question was about the jQuery library, not the jQuery mobile framework.

Comment: @martin there is no mention of either on the question. And this is the closest to the official instance.

Comment: jQuery means [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/), jQuery-mobile means [jquerymobile.com](http://jquerymobile.com/). If the question truly was about the jQuery mobile framework then it warrants an edit. Using the browser compatibility matrix would give false negatives for the library. For example IE6 works perfectly fine _"C-grade – Basic, non-enhanced HTML experience that is still functional"_ only applies to the mobile framework. Answer is misleading in relation to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Should work just fine in current Opera Mobile - if you target older versions (<9.5 AFAIK) you'd need to watch out for this: 
http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/show.dml/1665828

Comment: Opera Mobile, for Android 1.5 (I got stuck with this on a Samscum Behold II) does not support javascript.

Comment: You meant Opera Mini, right? Even Opera Mini supports some JavaScript but due to the client-proxy-server setup there are limitations to what you can expect.