# How to hide content with the same button that shows it?

Tags: html

I am currently using

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('history').style.display='block';return(false);">
```

To show content labelled with "history" when I click a certain button. How do I set it so that same button hides the content? I tried adding the same code again and replacing "get" with "hide" and "return(false)" to return(true) as that seemed logical to me but when I click the button nothing happens now (perhaps I have not understood something).

What is the easiest way to have the same button show and hide content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use jQuery (as has already been noted), you can do the following with pure JavaScript:

```
 var element = document.getElementById("someElement");
 if(element.style.display == "none") element.style.display = "block";
 else element.style.display = "none";
```

Place this in a function, and pass that function to the the `onclick` attribute of your element.

Comment: @Tocco - sometimes (in my opinion, anyway, especially if jQuery is not being used elsewhere) simple pure JS solutions are better than jQuery simply because of speed. For example, have a look at the jQuery source for the toggle function, compared to the 3 lines in my answer: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using JQuery. Such things are pretty easy using it. In JQuery it's simple as the following line.

```
$("#history").toggle();
```

Comment: I'm not sure about JQuery as this is for a mobile website; do you know if it's compatible?

Comment: Check out this for JQuery mobile browser compatibility. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233292/jquery-and-mobile-browser-compatiblity ... There is also a mobile version of JQuery which is something that you should have a look. ^^