# JQuery Framework (not mobile) and Mobile Browser Support

Tags: jquery, browser, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery and mobile browser compatiblity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233292/jquery-and-mobile-browser-compatiblity)

I've seen the supporting browsers for JQuery, but I'm trying to find out if the owners of JQuery have evaluated which types of **mobile** browsers it is supported on, which would include common ones (FireFox mobile, Chrome mobile, Opera Mobile, etc.) and internal browsers.  Just to note, I'm **not** talking about JQuery Mobile, but the JQuery framework only.

Everything seems to be pointing to JQuery Mobile only, so I get a lot of false positives in searching.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure whether or not you are referring to the jQuery library (the core) or jQuery UI?

If you are referring to the library (the core), then you will find that it will be almost 100% supported on all mobile browsers out in the wild. The reason I say this is that jQuery does not really do much other than provide wrapper methods to the existing JS objects. jQuery feature detects and tries a method and if it fails reverts to another method and if that fails another and so on. Also when I say "Almost" you may find a few peculiarities in regards to how it measures offsets, fires events (mouse events such as hover being the obvious one).

So all in all, you probably will not find a magic table stating which mobile browsers jQuery supports because the short answer is... all of them, and the long answer is that yes there may be some small peculiarities that you may encounter, although one would expect none of them to be critical.

Comment: JQuery only, not JQuery UI.  Thanks.

Comment: Then as I said unless you are going to do some crazy animations that have dynamic offsets and need to manage eccentric events then you can consider it 100% mobile supported - FYI jQuery is not a framework :-)